# Light in the scene window got way brighter after upgrading to Unity 2018.2.18f1 but the game window shows light correctly

Tags: unity-game-engine, light

So I had a project that I created using unity 2017.3 now I decided to move to  Unity 2018.2.18f1 and notice a very annoying problem that I can't seem to solve,
the lighting in the scene window got way too bright on the other hand in the game window even before hitting play it shows the correct light. here is an image of the issue:
[image]

I tried everything out there that worked on past versions with no results, trying removing auto generate and generating the lightmap manually, tried to change the reflection source from skybox to custom didn't work.

although in the game it self the light is correct so it didn't really break the project but it is really annoying designing levels this way

any insight on this would be great.

Comment: Updating Unity while making your game is not really a good idea unless there is a big bug that was fixed in the new version. I say this because there is a possibility something would break. Since you've tried "auto generate" I suggest you delete the light and create a new one. I suspect the light has something to do with this. Not entirely sure.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion it did actually work i don't know why i didn't try this simple fix, it is weird though it is as though lights created here behave differently, as for updating unity you are absolutely right , but there was a new feature that i really wanted to use for the game so I had to do this.

Comment: It's totally fine you need to update for new feature. I will leave an answer this I think it will be helpful to others in the feature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes, issues occur when upgrading a project to another Unity version. If the issue is related to lighting do the following in order:

**1**. Delete the lights in the current scene then create new lights. For some reason, there seems to be light issues carrying it's settings to the new Unity version and creating new lights usually fixes it.

**2**. Go to *Windows* --> *Lighting* --> *Settings* then go to the *Scene* tab. Scroll down and disable *Auto Generate* checkbox then click the *Generate Lightning* button.

**3**.Go to *Assets* --> *Reimport All*.

**4**. If everything above did not work, go your Project's Library folder then delete it. Restart Unity.

Comment: Where in the world did the world's most wonderful Programmer go?

Comment: Hope you are doing ok these days, Programmer!

Comment: I see I'm not the only one worried about our friend. Best wishes Programmer!